# Clone Ubuntu 20.04 on NAS

Tags: networking, mount, backup

What are the steps to clone Ubuntu 20.04 to a Network Attached Storage (NAS) device, and how can I ensure a successful and reliable backup or deployable configuration for other systems?

At the moment, I am using the backup solution provided by Ubuntu, but it doesn't seem to be a suitable fit for my needs. I have also come across Clonezilla, but I haven't found any NAS solution available with it.

Thank you for your support